# How can I align a button to the right of an h3 tag and keep them vertically aligned?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking for the most efficient bootstrap solution to align a button vertically centered next to an h3 tag

```css
    button{
padding: 10px 18px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Alerts</h3>
      <button>Add Alert</button>
    </div
  </div
</body
```

I want it to look like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can change the DOM structure, can you put the button inside the h3 tag?

```
<h3 class="panel-title">Alerts <button  class="btn btn-danger">Add Alert</button></h3>
```

Also, add a margin to add separation from the text

```
button{
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that h3 is a block element, try to put this...

```
   h3 {
      display:inline-block;
}
```